# Singleton returning two instances

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, singleton

I'm trying to use a singleton (PhotoStorage) to provide an arrayList of Photo objects, but it seems that the PhotoStorage instance is not behaving as a singleton (two instances).

I am using dagger to inject this singleton into a class named PhotoInteractor. The objectGraph seems A-OK up to this point.
The same PhotoInteractor instance is used in three fragments in a viewpager. These fragments are all instantiated at runtime:

**RecentFragment:**

[image: Recent_Fragment]

**HistoryFragment:**

[image: History_Frag]

Notice how the instance @4067 of the PhotoInteractor is the same for both fragments.

Also:

- mAppContext@4093: same
- photoStorage@4094: same

When I click a photo object (grid image) from RecentFragment, the PhotoStorage.addPhoto(url) method is called. This correctly adds the photo object to the photoStorage instance array (4094). That much is OK.

**Problem:**

When I close the applicaton, it is intended that the **PhotoStorage.savePhotosToFile** method serialzes this arrayList object into JSON on the filesystem.

The following method is called from the same PhotoInteractor instance:

```
@Override
public void savePhotos(){
    photoStorage.get(mAppContext).savePhotosToFile();
}
```

When I debug the application, the **PhotoStorage.get** method already has a singleton instance, but what appears to be a 2nd instance!

```
//Singleton enforcement
public static PhotoStorage get(Context c){
    if(sPhotoStorage == null){
        sPhotoStorage = new PhotoStorage(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sPhotoStorage;
}
```

This means that the ArrayList of photos will always be empty since it is a new instance of PhotoStorage. I’m not sure where it is instantiating itself from.

**Edit - Added PhotoStorage.class:**

```
public class PhotoStorage{
    private ArrayList<Photo> mPhotos;
    private PhotoJSONer mSerializer;
    private static PhotoStorage sPhotoStorage;
    private static Context mAppContext;
    private static final String PHOTOS_DATABASE = "photos.json";
    public static final String TAG = PhotoStorage.class.getSimpleName();

public PhotoStorage(Context appContext){
    mSerializer = new PhotoJSONer(appContext, PHOTOS_DATABASE);
    try{
        mPhotos = mSerializer.loadPhotos();
    }catch(Exception e){
        mPhotos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    }
}

//Singleton enforcement
public static PhotoStorage get(Context c){
    if(sPhotoStorage == null){
        sPhotoStorage = new PhotoStorage(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sPhotoStorage;
}

public ArrayList<Photo> getPhotos(){
    return mPhotos;
}

public Photo getPhoto(String url){
    for(Photo p: mPhotos){
        if(p.getUrl() == url)
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}

public void deletePhoto(String url){
    Log.i(TAG, "deleted photo");
    mPhotos.remove(url);
}

public void addPhoto(Photo photo){
    Log.i(TAG, "added photo");
    mPhotos.add(photo);
}

public boolean savePhotosToFile(){
    try{
        mSerializer.savePhotos(mPhotos);
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you please show `PhotoStorage` class complete?

Comment: Can you also please show us the code that you invoke when the app is closed (I am more interested in the way how do you detect this situation)?

Comment: In `savePhotos()`, instead of `photoStorage.get()` should it be `PhotoStorage.get()`? You want to make sure you invoke the static `get()` method, no?

Comment: Please check the comment of 323go and if that's not the problem, let us know.

Comment: @323go - I changed these as you mentioned. Still getting the same result with multiple instances.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads? Then you need to make this threadsafe. And why is there a public constructor? Shouldn't it be private and hidden behind `get`? Maybe someone else is calling it?

Comment: Also, if you are using Dagger to inject instances, cannot Dagger also take care of singletons (instead of you having to write the static field and method)? Not too familar with Dagger, but I thought one effect of DI was to get rid of these "resource lookup" methods.

Comment: @Thilo - yes, it appears that dagger can take care of singletons quite effectively. I am currently testing this by removing the singleton pattern from the application.

Comment: It turns out that I was able to drop the singleton pattern in favor of dagger injection. In case anyone is curious, I injected the PhotoStorage singleton into the PhotoInteractor class, which is responsible for relaying queries to a backend/data file:

    Module(injects = PhotoInteractorImpl.class
            ,addsTo = ApplicationModule.class)

public class PhotoStorageModule{

    Provides
    Singleton
        public PhotoStorage providePhotoStorage(BaseApplication application){
            return new PhotoStorage(application.getApplicationContext());
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing [Singletton pattern](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) in the correct way,

> The Singleton design pattern addresses all of these concerns. With the Singleton design pattern you can:
>   **Ensure that only one instance of a class is created**
>   Provide a global point of access to the object

In your case, we don't see `PhotoStorage` class but this call comes from an instance, what is not allowed by [Singletton pattern](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton):

```
photoStorage.get(mAppContext).savePhotosToFile();
//↑ instance call WRONG!!
```

This line works, but as your `get` method is `static` is not a good practice as [Karakuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207921/karakuri) pointed and also breaks the [Singletton pattern](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) definition.

```
public static PhotoStorage get(Context c){
```

**SOLUTION**
To make `photoStorage.get()` invalid and create a correct [Singletton pattern](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) you must:

- declare the `getInstance()` method static in the class (here `PhotoStorage`)
- hide default constructor to avoid instances of the class
- create private constructors if necessary
- call `getInstance()` it in a static way:

```
class PhotoStorage { 
    // hidding default constructor
    private PhotoStorage () {};

    // creating your own constructor but private!!!
    private PhotoStorage(Context appContext){
        mSerializer = new PhotoJSONer(appContext, PHOTOS_DATABASE);
        try{
            mPhotos = mSerializer.loadPhotos();
        }catch(Exception e){
            mPhotos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
        }
    }

    //Singleton enforcement
    public synchronized static PhotoStorage get(Context c){
        if(sPhotoStorage == null){
            sPhotoStorage = new PhotoStorage(c.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sPhotoStorage;
    }
}
```

Then you can make static call from everywhere the class scope allows:

```
@Override
public void savePhotos(){
      PhotoStorage.get(mAppContext).savePhotosToFile();
    //↑ static call CORRECT!!
}
```

**UPDATE:**
 if your app have several threads and singleton getInstance requests may overlapp, there is a [double check syncronized singletton pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2) you can apply:

```
//Singleton enforcement
public synchronized static PhotoStorage get(Context c){
    if(sPhotoStorage == null){
        synchronized(PhotoStorage.class) {
            if(sPhotoStorage == null) {
                sPhotoStorage = new PhotoStorage(c.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can invoke static methods from an instance, it's just not good practice.

Comment: You can even invoke static methods from a `null` instance. And yes, it is bad practice, and there is a compiler warning (which should be an error IMO).

Comment: Don't forget to make `get` synchronized, or else two threads could race and both create the singleton.

Comment: added `synchronized` and updated with more info to synchronize if necessary

Comment: @JordiCastilla - Thanks for the explanation. I think the main issue was with the constructor. Setting it to public will call it by default...I'm currently testing changes and will have a result shortly.